# Cannot run process npm install : file not found

Tags: node.js, npm, teamcity

I am trying to build a project in [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) server. The only build step is to run `npm install`

For this I created the following build step:

**Runner type:** Command Line

**Step name:** Install

**Run:** Executable with parameters

**Command executable:** npm install

**Command parameters:** *none*

This command gives the following error:

> [15:51:51]    Step 1/1: Install (Command Line)
>
> > [15:51:51]  [Step 1/1] Starting: npm install
> >
> > [15:51:51]  [Step 1/1] in directory: /path/to/repo/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/26cbe246a44af5d8
> >
> > [15:51:51]  [Step 1/1] Cannot run process npm install : file not found
> >
> > [15:51:51]  [Step 1/1] Step Install (Command Line) failed with unexpected error
> >
> > [15:51:52]  Publishing internal artifacts
> >
> > [15:51:52]  [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
> >
> > [15:51:52]  [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1
> >     file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher] [15:51:52]   Build finished

Why can't my build agent not able to run a simple `npm install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was trying to locate *npm install* command instead of *npm*.

So, I set `install` as a command parameter and not the command itself like so:

**Command executable:** npm

**Command parameters:** install

...and it worked

Answer (score -1):

What is the output from executing npm? Do you have it installed in the agent that is running the build?

Comment: Avoid posting questions as answers - this belongs in a comment.

Comment: Figured it out, see my answer. Thanks anyways